# Assets are not loading when navigating to different pages in Next.js

Tags: next.js, routes, assets

When I navigate from one page to another in Next.js, my page content--such as images, text, and style padding--doesn't render properly. However, when I refresh the page or copy the link and open it directly in a new tab, everything displays correctly. This problem only occurs when I go through routes in Next.js. I think the assets are not loading properly when switching routes.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Next.js Link Component:** Ensure that you're using **Next.js' Link component for client-side navigation instead of regular anchor tags ().** Next.js' Link component prefetches assets for the linked page, which can help ensure that assets are loaded properly when navigating between routes.

**Example**

```
import Link from 'next/link';

<Link href="/other-page">
  <a>Go to Other Page</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Yes, i m using Link instead of anchor tag but its not working